# Cambiar background-color según value HTML, con JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Si el valor es azul que el `style="background-color:"` tenga el valor *0000FF*, si es "rojo" tenga el valor *FF0000*.

```
<p id="color">Azul</p>

<script>
color = document.getElementById("color").innerHTML;
if (color == "azul"){
    document.getElementById("color").style.background-color = "#0000FF";
}
if (color == "rojo"){
    document.getElementById("color").style.background-color = "#FF0000";
}
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Qué es un typo?

Comment: Que escribiste algo mal, lo cual de hecho sigue presente en tu pregunta pues la condición a evaluar si se cumple o no en el if debe ir entre paréntesis

Comment: Luego el último typo sería que el valor en hexadecimal que vas a asignar si la condición se cumple debe ir precedido por el símbolo de # y entre comillas asi "#0000FF"

Comment: Muy amable BetaM

Comment: Por último la propiedad background color cuando la asignas mediante JS no va como en CSS sino que se escribe así: **backgroundColor**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como ha dicho @BetaM hay que tener claro varios puntos:

1. El operador "**=**" es una asignación y el operador "**==**" es la
   comparación y lo que tú necesitas para resolver este código.
2. Para la asignación de colores hexadecimales debes hacerlo como el te indica: "**#0000FF**"
3. La propiedad que necesitas para el color de fondo es: **backgroundColor**

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <p id="color">Azul</p>

      <script>
        var color = document.getElementById("color").innerHTML;
        if (color == "Azul") {
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#0000FF";
        }
        if (color == "Rojo") {
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Para modificar el color de fondo del párrafo:

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <p id="color">Azul</p>

      <script>
        var color = document.getElementById("color").innerHTML;
        if (color == "Azul") {
          document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#0000FF";
        }
        if (color == "Rojo") {
          document.getElementById("color").style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
        }
      </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ese código cambia el color de fondo de todo el body. ¿Cómo sería para modificar el fondo de <p> cuyo id="color"? Gracias.

Comment: Te he dejado el snippet para cambiar el color de fondo del parrafo con id="color".
Primero debes seleccionar el elemento que te interesa cambiar de fondo y luego aplicas los cambios que necesites sobre él.

Comment: Es curioso que si tengo varios elementos con el id color, sólo se lo aplica al primero que encuentra. ¿Puede ser porque el concepto de id debe ser para un sólo elemento? Para multiples mejor utilizar class.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <body>
      <p id="color">Azul</p>

<script>

    function cambiarColorFondo(cambiarColor) {
        let colores = document.getElementById("color");
        document.body.style.display="flex";
        document.body.style.justifyContent="center";
        colores.style.fontSize = "900%";
        colores.style.color="white";
        colores.textContent = cambiarColor;
        if (colores.textContent === "Azul") {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#0000FF";
   
        } else if (colores.textContent === "Rojo") {
            document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
      
        }
    }

    cambiarColorFondo("Azul");//Con esta función puedes cambiar el color

</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Básicamente he puesto **textContent** en vez de **innerHTML** para comparar el contenido del elemento **colores** con cadenas de texto **Azul y Rojo** . He mejorado un poquito para que se pueda ver el tamaño de la letra y el color adecuado. Si amigos, a veces soy exigente y no puedo evitar .